# File copy duration in Windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-explorer

The case is as following:

Suppose you have two folders equal in their size, but the first folder have lets say **3** files, and the second have **10000** files; copying the first folder (with the less files number) will finish in a much, much less time than the other folder, even the expected time to finish for copying the second folder will be completely inaccurate.

What is the technical explanation for this? Is it related to an initialization and disposal of resources that is being carried out for each file that will be copied ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are copying second folder, in that folder large number of files, that should be take much time in compare of first because every file store in seprate sectors in you hard-disk or storage device.